# django-admin.py startproject mysite not working well on windows 7

Tags: python, django

I'm learning django and I did successfully start a site on Windows XP by following the tutorial.

However, on Windows 7 when I issued:

```
django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

python.exe was started and a window appeared to ask me to choose either python.exe or other program to open a file....

Did I do anything wrong or there are more tricks for windows 7?

Answer (score 14):

That's already been reported to the django, see http://bugs.python.org/issue7936
And these's an solution:
open regedit and find python.exe like this
"C:\Python26\python.exe" "%1"
change it to 
"C:\Python26\python.exe" "%1" %*

Comment: For instance, under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\python.exe\shell\open\command

Comment: I had the same problem as the OP, this fixed it for me. Thanks.

Comment: This worked for me, I had to change two register keys:  HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\py_auto_file\shell\open\command  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Applications\python.exe\shell\open\command

Comment: Is there a solution for Python27? I've tried looking for this and I can't find it where you say it should be located..

Answer (score 13):

This is what worked for me:
I already had c:\python27 and c:\python27\Scripts in PATH.

1. Copy django-admin.py and django-admin-script.py from c:\python27\Scripts to your desired folder
2. with cmd go to that folder and run  > django-admin startproject mysite

Note that if I doesn't type `python` windows just opens the `django-admin.py` in editor.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same error when I ran `django-admin.py` on the command prompt. I couldn't create a projects.

I tried to run *Regedit* by using Find to Search python.exe and then adding `%%` but it was not sufficient.
I then added the necessary Path to the *System PATH* as shown below.

**Open:**
*Control Panel* -> *System* -> *Advanced* -> *Environment Variables* -> *PATH*.

**Add to the PATH:**

```
C:\Python27\python.exe;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\bin
```

It Work! Now I can Create Django Projects and applications Using *Command* on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

In latest django(1.11.7 for now) , simple `django-admin` would work, instead of `django-admin.py` .

Comment: In Django 2+ confirmed to work as well. In cmd.exe simply using 'django-admin ...' will work. ```pip3 install django``` will install a 'django-admin.exe' script in the 'Scripts' folder of your activate python environment.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem i followed [django-admin.py startproject mysite not working well on windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870262/django-admin-py-startproject-mysite-not-working-well-on-windows-7)
and found that the python files still associated with my text editor. 
Changing the necessary registry keys fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem but don't worry its simple to solve this problem, just add "C:\Users\Nik's\myenv\Scripts" to the enviroment veriables and its done.
The address may be differnt in your pc as it depends where you install it.

Answer (score 0):

Change the first line of django-admin.py `#!/usr/bin/env python` to for example `#!D:\Program Files\Python\python.exe` (Where you install your `python.exe`,that's my directory); it works.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple in Windows:

1-Go to C: \ Python34 \ Scripts

2-Right click on django-admin.py

3-Select open with

4-Select default program

5-Select Laucher Python for Windows (Console)

6- Run the command in CMD Windows `python django-admin.py startproject mysite`

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 8.1, I faced the same problem. In my case when I tried to create my project, it would open the contents of the page in Internet Explorer window rather than creating the project folder. I became curious of what exactly was this django-manage.py. After searching, I got to django-admin.py file in the path C:\Python34\Scripts and I right clicked on it chose to open with default program of Launcher Python for Windows(Console).

Again I got back to the CMD and in my project directory I entered:
django-admin.py startproject mysite

And worked just fine.!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue and when I ran the Python installer again and clicked on the repair option, it magically fixed everything for me. Now, I can run `django-admin` straight from CMD.

Answer (score 0):

1. first of all make sure that python/Scripts is in your path
2. run "django-admin startproject mysite" instead of "django-admin.py startproject mysite"

Answer (score 0):

I get the same problem for Windows 10. Here is how I resolve it:

1. I run the terminal **CMD** with *administrator right*. How to do that ? Right click on the terminal and click on *Run as administrator*.
2. I install *django* by doing: `python -m pip install django`. You can check that *django* is really installed by doing: `python -m pip freeze`. If you see django in the list, then *django* is installed.
3. Finally, I create my *django* project by doing: `django-admin startproject project-name`.

**NB:** For step 3, you don't need the terminal with administrator right.