# Can't open file 'django-admin.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm using Python 2.7, Django 1.2.5 and on Windows 7.

I am not sure what I've done. I used to be able to create Django projects like

```
python django-admin.py startproject test
```

Now however I get this error.

> Can't open file 'django-admin.py': 
>   [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I can type the following which works.

```
python C:\Python27\Scripts\django-admin.py startproject test
```

How can I have it the way it used to be? *Not having the type the full path to the django-admin.py file.*

Things I've already tried:

I uninstalled Python and manually removed the values from the PATH variable in Windows. Reinstalled Python. Deleted Django and reinstalled it too.

I've added **C:\Python27\Scripts** to my **PATH** and **PYTHONPATH** variable under **Environmental Variables** in Windows.

### Any suggestions?

My PATH variable contains

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\ActiveState Komodo Edit 6\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\django-apps;F:\My_Projects;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Mercurial\bin;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts
```

PYTHONPATH has

```
C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Lib;C:\Python27\DLLs;C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\django-apps;f:\my_projects
```

Comment: are you sure that some other app hasn't messed up your PATH? please paste it here.

Comment: i think you're right. something has messed up my PATH variable. I've posted it above so you can see what is in it.

Comment: See this post fixed it for me:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870262/django-admin-py-startproject-mysite-not-working-well-on-windows-7

Answer (score 15):

I had this same problem with slightly newer versions of Python 2.7.x and Django - and it is not the PATH. This is all I had to do to fix it in Windows XP:

1. Find a .py file (any, even a blank).
2. Right click on it and choose: "Open with>" and then select "Choose program...".
3. This pops up a list of all programs - select `python`, and check the box "Always use the selected program to open this kind of file" and then click <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Checking this box resets file associations and fixes this problem for the command line.

The cause of the problem: Telling Windows to open up .py files in a text editor as default.

Comment: Great solution to a simple mistake.

Answer (score 10):

If `C:\Python27\Scripts` is in your Path, just type in:

```
django-admin.py startproject proj
```

There should be a file association with .py and try to execute. If you prefix with `python` the next command is a file path.

I've never been able to do `python django-admin.py` -- I get the same error you describe.

Make sure python is associated with `.py`. You can check via file properties (opens with...) or typing `assoc .py` in cmd.

Comment: I've made sure the associations are correct. I also tried django-admin.py startproject test but it dumps all the information regarding django-admin-.py

Comment: I just installed django to replicate, django-admin.py startproject test works. Sounds like your setup is not passing the argument to django-admin.py since you should not be getting list but an error message

Comment: does ftype Python.File reveal `"C:\Python27\python.exe" "%1" %*`

Comment: yes ftype python.File gives me "C:\Python27\python.exe" "%1" %*

Comment: What I don't understand is that django-admin.py blah actually invokes the script and returns the help info.

Comment: agreed it's strange. typing django-admin.py help gives exactly the same thing. as you say it invokes and doesn't take in the argument. but if i specify the full location of django-admin.py then it works. never experienced this before.

Comment: I have had the exact same problem, and I was able to make it work (for the first time) using the syntax: python c:\Python27\Scripts\django-admin.py startproject myprojectname

Answer (score 5):

Here is what I did to get this working:

- Installed Python 2.7 to C:\Python27 using the install package for Windows at python.org
- I chose to install the latest release version of Django (1.3) (*not the development trunk*)
- Installed Django following the instructions here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/install/
- I'm only doing local development, so I skipped install of Apache and mod_wsgi (as directed in Django instructions)
- I don't need a database for my app, so I skipped "Get your database running" section in Django instructions; and I skipped "Remove any old versions of Django" (didn't have any installed)
- I skipped down the instructions to "Installing an official release"
- I installed bsdtar as directed in order to untar the release files on my windows machine - ran no problem.
- Being on Windows, I started a cmd shell with admin privileges and ran the command "setup.py install" - ran no problem
- I followed the instruction to verify Django install: running import django and django.print get_version() - returned 1.3, success
- Then it came time to run django-admin.py startproject myproject - I received similar errors to the above, and when trying to run django-admin.py from within the python interpreter, I received syntax errors pointing at the arguments.  Strange.
- Found this thread, and ran this, which worked: c:\Python27\Scripts\django-admin.py startproject myproject and it worked.
- Still curious, I wanted to see if I could make it work from cmd prompt, without the paths, since it seemed that should work - and it didn't.

This is what I did beyond the install instructions that made it work for me on Windows:

- Verified the file associations, using info from this post - all associations good.
- Used Start|Computer|System Properties|Advanced System Properties|Environment Variables dialog to set the environment variables as follows:
- Set New System Variable: `PYTHONPATH` = `c:\Python27\Lib;c:\Python27\Scripts`
- Edit existing User variable: `PATH` added: `C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts to the end.`

The result:

- .py files now execute from cmd command line (no need to run python interpreter first)
- e.g. the command django-admin.py startproject mynewproject ran just fine.

Please post any questions in the comments, maybe I can help.

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible you associated your .py files with another program (like a text editor)?  I had this problem, too, after associating .py files with gedit.

I'd have the problem if I did this:

```
python django-admin.py startproject myproject
```

Once I reassociated .py files to python this problem went away.

Answer (score 3):

Gosh! It drove me crazy! Just do the following!

```
python C:\python27\scripts\django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be with the file association. After adding the PATH variables, remove all "py" associations instead of linking them to your Python executable:

Remove the file type ".py " from the registry or by using a small 
free tool for Windows Vista/Windows 7 called 'Unassoc' (google for Windows 7 unassoc).

In my case simply unassociating the file type was not enough. I had to remove the file type entirely using the unassoc tool.

Now you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it! It's the command line to open a `file .py`.

It has to be like so:

```
"C:\Python27\python.exe" "%1" %*
```

mine was:

```
"C:\Python27\python.exe" "%1" without the final %*
```

I've used `FileTypesMan` to edit because Windows 7 can't edit this property.

Comment: There are two relatively unknown windows commands called `FTYPE` and `ASSOC`, which can be used to change this. (probably what FileTypesMan" is using... And easier to use than registry editing.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was solved by adding the path to django-admin.py.

The instruction in windows with a python 7 and django 1.11 is:

```
python c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\bin\django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

Answer (score 0):

First, set the path in PowerShell (in your $profile) like this:

```
$env:PATH = "C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\bin\;"
```

Then, to get .py files to open in PowerShell rather than cmd, add this line:

```
$env:PATHEXT += ";.py"
```

Finally, to be able to just type "django-admin" and have it work, add this line:

```
function django-admin {python (gcm django-admin.py | resolve-path) $args}
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

After I installed an IDE, I had a similar (if not the same) problem.  Sure enough, the .py "Open With" setting had been changed, and changing it back to the Python Launcher for Windows did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, I used

```
django-admin startproject test
```

and it seemed to have worked.

Answer (score 0):

Since the path is too long, I moved the folders to a shorter path inside C: /. This way I call it faster, there is a problem with the route. I use Windows 10 with Django 3.0.5, so it turns out like this: python C:\Python38\Scripts\django-admin.py startproject test

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was the installation of Visual Studio.

I tried to install django-admin, which is usely automatically set up:

```
pip3 install django-admin
```

and it gave to me :

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required.
```

So, I install Microsoft Visual Studio, and then it works.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you cd is where you saved your [Notepad++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) Python file. If you saved it under your \Python27\ directory, then while in the terminal or [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) window, type `cd C:\Python27` and press enter.

This will open that directory so when you type `python filename.py` it will find it and run it. Just remember to save all .py files to the same directory, so you have no further problems.

Answer (score -1):

No Windows, usei:

```
python -m django startproject mysite
```