# how to start a new django project from any directory

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-admin

I'm running a windows 8 machine. I've installed django using pip and everything looks to be done correctly. running python 2.7 and have django 1.6 installed.

```
python c:\python27\scripts\django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

this is the only way I've found to start a new project from any directory; otherwise I would have to make my project and run it from that specific folder. I want to be able to just:

```
python django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

from any directory - or more simply:

```
django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

from anywhere. I have:

```
c:\python27\;c:\python\scripts\
```

in my environment variables.

Comment: what about adding `c:\python27\scripts\ ` to your path?

Answer (score 1):

Not a windows guy, but try running the command from the directory where you want your site to live.

```
cd C:\Sites
python django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

If that doesn't work, then is that you don't have Django in your PATH. Add Django to your PATH. Otherwise you'll have to do

```
python C:\path\to\django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

Also check out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/install/ for more documentation on setting up your Django environment.
Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a .cmd file that contains

`python c:\python27\scripts\django-admin.py %1 %2 %3 %4 %5`

name it django-admin.cmd and put it in c:\windows\system32

Then you should be able to

`django-admin startproject mysite` anywhere

Answer (score 0):

it seems like the problem is the .py files's default open way.
first, find a .py file.
right click on it,and select "open with" , here u should use python as your default open mode

then restart your cmd, it should be worked.

here is another same problem [Can't open file 'django-admin.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299241/cant-open-file-django-admin-py-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `virtualenv`'s.  After creating an env, installing django, and activating and env `django-admin` commands should become available.  [A recent similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20768273/594589)