# Problems with django and virtualenv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

**EDIT**: Well, looks like I already found a solution. I just used the full path to the django-admin.py file and it worked.

---

So you're aware, in my virtualenv I'm running Python 2.7.5 32 Bit.

I'm following [Tango with Django Chapter 3.2](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/setup.html).

It says to run:

```
django-admin.py startproject tango_with_django_project
```

It responds with:

```
ImportError: No module named django.core
```

I've already tried fixing the PYTHONPATH using `add2virtualenv`, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Currently my PYTHONPATH in the virtualenv is C:\Users\Liam\Envs\rango\Scripts\python.exe

I want to change it to C:\Users\Liam\Envs\rango\Lib\Scripts

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't use windows (so hopefully the following is still up to date), but I believe you need to [activate](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/win/#virtualenv) your env to get it to work:

> To use an environment, run the activate.bat batch file in the Scripts
>   subdirectory of that environment. Your command prompt will change to
>   show the active environment. Once you have finished working in the
>   current virtual environment, run the deactivate.bat batch file to
>   restore your settings to normal.

Of course you could also directly reference your scripts, as you have already discovered