# django-admin.py startproject asks to chose default program

Tags: python, django, django-admin

When trying to start a project with django using : django-admin.py startproject  a pop up window opens asking to choose a default program to use.

The two main programs it shows are : Visual studio and Notepad.

I have already set the python in 'PATH' and same with the pip which i used to install django.

What should I do to fix that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

run

```
 python <PATH>/django-admin.py startproject
```

your system is not  configured to run `.py` files.  read [here](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/windows.html#how-do-i-make-python-scripts-executable)

Comment: After using 'python <PATH>/django-admin.py startproject <projectname>' it sais : "The system cannot find the file specified".

Comment: <PATH> means the full path to your django-admin.py

Comment: Ain`t that enough to change directory?

Comment: yep but I don't think you want to create your project in the same dir where django-admin.py

Comment: Alright I misunderstood you at first but now I got it and it worked.
Can you explain why I had to add that python <PATH> and it doesn`t work without it?

Comment: When you launch python you start another process. It does not known where django-admin is.

Comment: That`s wierd cuz it worked for me witouht the <PATH> on another computer.

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299241/cant-open-file-django-admin-py-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory