# Python cannot find file in current directory with PowerShell

Tags: python-2.7, powershell

I'm trying to set up a new coding environment for myself so that I may learn Python at home on Windows 10. I already installed Python 2.7 and I am able to run it in PowerShell using the `python` command. However, when I try to get it to run other files (namely `HelloWorld.py`) it is getting an error

> C:\Python27\python.exe: can't open file 'HelloWorld.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I am in the same folder as `HelloWorld.py` on PowerShell and when I type `ls`, it appears on the screen. Most of the other questions I've seen on here were resolved by changing the environment variables in System to include `python`, but I have already done that. I am looking for anything else to try.

Comment: How *exactly* are you trying to "get it to run other files"? What is the exact command that gives you the error?

Comment: You either aren't in the correct directory or something is not quite right with your command line.

Comment: I think your situation is quite similar with this one, hope it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299241/cant-open-file-django-admin-py-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory