# python.exe don't see files in Windows

Tags: python, windows

I write in CMD:

```
C:\ProjectStray\Model>python smth.py
```

[image]

But get:

```
python: can't open file 'smth.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

`python C:\ProjectStray\Model\smth.py` also not works

My files:

[image]

On another windows environments that works.
How can I fix that?

Comment: And where do you write it? CMD?

Comment: @BlackThunder you are right, in cmd

Comment: Have you tried to debug? Have you tried changing the directory?

Comment: @BlackThunder I tried to change the directory - that didn't help, also tried to reinstall python - same results. Looks like I should reinstall Windows =)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't open file 'django-admin.py': \[Errno 2\] No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299241/cant-open-file-django-admin-py-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: @MilanVelebit not exactly, because using `python C:\ProjectStray\Model\smth.py` not works in my case, also solutions from that post didn't help

Comment: Have you tried the `dir` command to list the directory content? Could also be that your python file actually has a `.py.py` extension or something else weird going on with your filename

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but I just started windows reinstalling

Comment: Windows reinstall solved this issue =)