# django-admin.py startproject doesn't work, why? FIXED

Tags: django

The command *django-admin.py startproject mysite* doesn't work.

Also for more information, here is a screenshot of what happens: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrL96.png.

I also tried this using full path to django: *C:\Python27\Scripts\django-admin.py startproject mysite*.

Neither of these commands create anything.

---

FIXED: Here is the answer: [django-admin.py is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989825/django-admin-py-is-not-working?rq=1)

Comment: -1 for posting a screenshot instead of cutting and pasting the text.

Comment: @DanielRoseman new user, can inform and wait, than we can close it anyways :)

Comment: So? You guys can't look at pictures?

Comment: possible duplicate of [django-admin.py is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989825/django-admin-py-is-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

himmip try `django-admin.py startproject mysite` in a directory where you want your project.

Plus, make sure you have Django installed by calling `python -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"` from the command line. It should print out django's version if its correctly installed.

Just like in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/).

Comment: Thanks. I ran 'python -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"' and got version 1.5.2, so that works.
But startproject is still not working, I ran the command in a directory for the project.

Comment: No problem. Did you check out the tutorial I listed above (the docs link)? Since we know django is installed correctly on your python path (assuming you did the version check in a dir out side of the django folder), every thing should work. Have you tired `python django-admin.py startproject mysite`? adding python makes it explicit that your executing a python file.

Answer (score 0):

Give the full path along with ahead python as $ python c:\Python27\Scripts\django-admin.py startproject project_name. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

i have also had this issues many times , generally it is due to the anti-virus firewall , therefore when you see something don't work , don't hesitate to check it fastly !