# when create a project in django, create a empty folder

Tags: python, django

I dont know why every time i create a project with this command, it creates an empty folder:

```
django-admin start-project myProject
```

These are the files that I have in my directory:

[image]

What I noticed is that I do not have the django-admin.py file, is that normal?
why when I execute the command, it does not throw me any error?

[image]

When I go to see the folder created previously, I find an empty folder:
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681216/django-admin-py-startproject-is-not-working, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989825/django-admin-py-is-not-working , and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18485841/django-admin-py-startproject-doesnt-work-why-fixed. How much you try to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by updating the django to a newer version

pip install --upgrade django==1.6.5.

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade django to at least 1.11, because of security reasons. Especially if you are storing some valuable (user) data. See the django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/upgrade-version/ for more information

Answer (score -1):

Try to reinstall Python and Django. **It has to help**.

---

Also, you use Python3.4, you should use more new Python.

Comment: 'Trying' something is not answer.