# Django-admin created an empty folder

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I created a virtual environment than I installed Django successfully but when i try to create a project with django-admin startproject `<project_name>` Django create an empty folder?

[image: img1]

[image: img1]

I tried the C:\path\virtualenv\Scripts\django-admin startproject name_project it still doesn't work

Comment: Which django/python version are you using? Also, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49799589/when-create-a-project-in-django-create-a-empty-folder) for possible solutions

Comment: I recognized that the antivirus did that and empty my folder. it works with me that way

Comment: For future refernce, write the answer yourself and auto-accept it. Hope it will be useful to someone in the future :) Which antivirus was that tho?

Answer (score -1):

I think the path is wrong. I mean to say you should be inside a virtual environment folder that is my-site in your case, then activate it, in the above image it was activated. But the main thing is you should be inside that my-site folder and then install django and run the django-admin startproject command. This is what I think the problem is.

Comment: I did what you said still the same

Comment: I recognized that the antivirus did that and empty my folder. it works with me that way.