# command "django-admin.py startproject mysite" not recognized

Tags: django

**EDIT:** I added the path to django-admin.py to my system path `(C:\Users\me\Downloads\Django-1.5.1\django\bin)` but even after this when I try to run django-admin.py startproject mysite, it asks me to pick a file to open with and even when I pick python.py, it opens in chrome for some reason. I also tried python django-admin.py startproject mysite but it says

> python: can't open file django-admin.py: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Any idea what is wrong?

I added python27 to the system path and when I open up cmd and switch to a directory `(C:\Users\me\djcode)` and then type in django-admin.py startproject mysite it says

> django-admin.py is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

When I try typing the command python django-admin.py startproject mysite, it says

> python: can't open file django-admin.py: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Any idea why?

In the djangobook (http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter02.html) it says

> django-admin.py should be on your system path if you installed Django via its setup.py utility

what does this mean? how do I add django-admin.py to my system path? I am not sure where django-admin.py even is.

Comment: In order to install Django in the system path you have to do a `python setup install` from a shell when you are in the root of folder containing Django (the `C:\Users\me\Downloads\Django-1.5.1\` folder) (I suppose you are on Windows). I don't understand if you have installed python or only added it to the system path.

Comment: still gives me the same error after trying this.. plus it said I already had it installed.

Comment: This post has the solution: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870262/django-admin-py-startproject-mysite-not-working-well-on-windows-7

Answer (score 67):

**Working !!**
If you are using window then first of all

create virtual environment

```
python -m venv venv
```

Then activate that environment

```
venv\Scripts\activate
```

Then install Django in that environment

```
pip install django
```

Then create django project named mysite

```
django-admin startproject mysite
```

Comment: Thanks it woked just fine for me, I'm a a Django beginner any advices ? or projects to contribute in as a beginner (I'm familiar with programming).

Comment: Where does it generate mysite?

Comment: @Sarah_A It generates mysite at the directory you run these commands in.

Answer (score 20):

I have the same problem because i have installed Django Manually. The solution for resolve :

1. Install Python https://www.python.org/downloads/ (if not installed)
2. Verify your **Path** : https://stackoverflow.com/a/17836439 It's very important or the next no work.
3. Install setuptool : Download the .py file here : https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py and execute this with python.
4. Install PIP with this command : `easy_install pip`
5. Clean Django : `pip uninstall django`
6. install Django : `pip install django`
7. Execut `django-admin.py startproject mysite` and enjoy.

If not OK, test `django-admin-script.py startproject mysite`. If is ok, your django installation is wrong.

Sorry for my bad english, i'm french :)

Answer (score 16):

Find the folder where django-admin.py is located. Then go to Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables . In the User Variables and/or System Variables, search for an entry called PATH. Modify it by adding the folder you found earlier, use the other entries as guidance, basically just make sure they're separated by `;`. If you have done all these steps, but are still in the same cmd prompt that you were using before doing them, close it and open a new one so it picks up on your changes.

Comment: after I started cmd again and run django-project.py startproject mysite, it asks me what I want to open the file with.. everytime I pick the python.py file, nothing happens, so I tried to pick the pythonw.py file and still nothing happens.

Comment: Download this script: https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/downloads/ez_setup.py and run it, to install SetupTools. After it runs successfully, close the command prompt and open a new one. Now run `easy_install django`. On my system, I then created C:\test, after Django finished installing, I ran `django-admin.py startproject testproject`, substitute `testproject` with whatever you want to call your project.

Comment: what do I run ez_setup.py with? when i double click the file or try to run it with cmd, it asks what I want to open with. I picked pythonw.py but that does nothing.. well, it appears to do nothing.. EDIT: nevermind, I did python ez_setup.py, it ran that way

Comment: You open a cmd prompt, cd into the folder where you downloaded it and run it like `python ez_setup.py`.

Comment: Hm okay, so now to run easy_install, I cd into the folder which has the easy_intall.pth file and then I tried easy_install django, it said that 'easy_install' is not recognized as a internal or external command, operable program or batch file. I tried python easy_install django and it said 'python: can't open file easy_install: [Errno 2] No such file directory.

Comment: Hey! My laptop froze when I clicked the discussion link, I restarted my laptop and tried to click the discussion link again and it froze again, I had to hold down the power button until it turned off, I think it is over heating.. Can we try to continue this tomorrow? Sorry :/ I will try closing and reopening cmd and seeing what happens, thanks for the help so far!

Comment: Yep, we can try later. I suggest trying to uninstall Python completely in the meantime, delete its folder from C:\, re-install again, then install SetupTools like I told you and then django.

Comment: Hey @pallandt,m are you there? Can we try re-installing everything right now?

Comment: nevermind, found the answer, this was the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870262/django-admin-py-startproject-mysite-not-working-well-on-windows-7

Comment: Well, glad you've fixed it.

Answer (score 11):

I've just created project using :

```
py -m django startproject Yourprojectname
```

or
python -m django startproject firstproject

Comment: Is this supposed to solve the problem? I do not see how. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 9):

I have tried all of the mentioned things however I was still unable to create a project using `django-admin startapp appname`. So I used `python -m django startproject appname` instead and was able to create the proejct

Answer (score 7):

For windows, the "django-admin" you need to create a project is an .exe file not a .py file and it is present at the following location:
    C:\Python27\Scripts 
so you have to add this location to your path.

Comment: django-admin.exe startproject myproject. It works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

- After running `pip install django` wait for the setup to finish and
  present you with a warning.
- From the warning copy the path of where django is installed. In my
  case it is
  `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\Scripts`
- Add that to `PATH` in environment variables and restart cmd or shell.

Comment: worked with Python3.9 and Django 3.1 and Windows 10

Comment: Worked in my case as well, thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this: django-admin startproject mysite

Comment: This helped. Thanks. To add, in Windows, django-admin.exe needs to be invoked which is done by what Martin has shown above.

Answer (score 3):

If it did not work for you even if you tried the command :

> django-admin startproject mysite

Here's what worked for me:

- Uninstall django

> pip uninstall django

- Add the below path to the PATH variables-

> C:\Users\System_Name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts

Note: In the above path, System_Name refers to the name of your laptop/pc.

- Install django again

> pip install django

You can check the version of django using django-admin --version

Answer (score 1):

You need to install django. It seems you have just downloaded it and expanded the archive.

1. Install [setuptools](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#setuptools)
2. Install [pip](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pip)
3. Open a command prompt and then type `pip install -U django` (or, you can download the [windows installer](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#django)).

Once you have done the above steps, you need to make sure `C:\Python27\Scripts` is in your `PATH`; otherwise the commands will not work.

To set `PATH`, go to `Environment Variables` from `My Computer` (right click and then go to Manage, then on the left, Advanced Settings).

Finally, you'll need to run `python django-admin.py` and not `django-admin.py`

Comment: I have follow all the step as you mention. I am using python33. I setup path C:\Python33\Tools\Scripts or My path are like this C:\Python33;C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages;C:\Python33\Tools\Scripts but also I am getting same error. 

python django-adming.py
python: can't open file 'django-adming.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: `django-admin.py` not `django-adming.py`

Answer (score 1):

this one workked for me
python 2.6.6
django 1.6.11
 `python C:\Python26\Scripts\django-admin.py startproject myapplication`

Answer (score 1):

Try using. exe instead of .py.
It worked for me

Comment: add some relevant exaplanation

Comment: C:\Python26\Scripts\django-admin.exe startproject myapplication

Answer (score 1):

Add the following address in the system path

`C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts`

{username} : enter your username

Answer (score 1):

Try this command: python -m django startproject myapp

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and tried many ways. Solved my problem by following these steps

```
Python installation manually
```

in my cmd

```
pip install Django    

pip install djangorestframework

pip install django-cors-headers

pip install virtualenvwrapper-win
```

Windows+r

```
sysdm.cpl
```

In Advanced Option, Environment Variables> In user variable edit

> path

```
C:\Users\mushf\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310

C:\Users\mushf\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Scripts
```

In System Variable> Edit

> path

```
C:\Program Files\Python310\Scripts\
C:\Program Files\Python310\
```

After that create my project folder in the desired location:

```
django-admin start project ProjectName
```

My preferable IDE is pycharm

Answer (score 1):

**Instructions for Windows**

You must have [pip](https://pypi.org/project/pip/) on your machine.
Open Visual Studio and open the project folder.

Open terminal from VS, Terminal tab. Go to the project directory.

```
pip3 install virtualenvwrapper
```

This must be done only the very first time you are setting up your environment.

Then run:

```
python -m venv env
```

Installs the needed files for running a virtual environment. You should see a folder added now. Create a virtual environment. Now activate it (i.e. start working in the virtual environment):

```
activate environment env\Scripts\activate
```

if activate doesn't work use this

```
env\Scripts\activate
```

Install Django in a virtual environment. If you want a specific version run:

```
pip install django==3.0.3
```

For the latest version just run:

```
pip install Django
```

To check the existing version:

```
pip freeze
```

To create a new project:

```
django-admin startproject simplesite
cd simplesite
python manage.py startapp helloworld
```

will create a new application in the project with a folder "helloworld"

```
python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8080
```

Open in your browser http://localhost:8080 to test the running server.

Ctrl+C to stop the server.

Answer (score 0):

copy the Django-admin.exe file into the folder you are using. the file can be found at python/python(version)/scripts. when you finish a folder should pop up in the name of your file

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the Django admin.py file which is present actually where you have installed python in C:\program files\Python or in my case it was located at administrator\appdata\local\programs\python you can check yours and just copy the file that is Django admin from script folder to your newly created folder

Answer (score 0):

I needed to update my System Environment Variable `path` so this answer helped me:

[Add “django-admin.py” path to command line on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17836439/6914806)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to activate the environment (env) before you run the command: 
`django-admin startproject myapp`

I had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

**For Windows user**:

**Step 1**: Open cmd in the project directory

**Step 2**: Run this in cmd : `python -c "import django; print(django.__path__)"`

**Step 3**: Go to the path and copy django-admin.exe to the current project directory

**Step 4**: Run this in cmd : `django-admin startproject DEMO`

**Happy Learning**,

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Before you run `django-admin.py startproject mysite`

1) You need to create a virtual enviroment on the folder that you want to store your project 
so run `pipenv install django==2.1` (if you dont have pipenv installed run 
`pip install --user pipenv`)

2) To run this virtual enviroment run `pipenv shell`

3)And finaly `django-admin.py startproject mysite`

Hope this works

Answer (score 0):

In my case I made a mistake installing django in a wide system manner and then it created `/usr/local/bin/django-admin` I uninstalled django through pip but it doesn't remove those files then when you type the command it tries to invoke that file but as it says the module django is not present.

Just remove those orphans files (use sudo if needed)

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/django-admin
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/django-admin.py
```

and try again (with your virtualenv activated) and it should takes the right module and works as usual!

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
step-1  --add environmental path
      C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38 
      C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts
     
step-2   pip install django
step-3   --run command in specific folder
         django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, a simple fix was reinstalling python. It turns out **I didn't select add to path**, when installing python the first time, and that is crucial.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using windows then goto (search)"advanced system settings/Environment veriables/New path" and add path of your python packeges folder, in my case its "C:\python38\Lib\site-packages".
may be you have other path of site-packages folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Pycharm then after creating New project just go to the file-->setting-->project-->serch Django-->install Django then go to the terminal type django-admin startproject name(whichever you want) press enter

Answer (score 0):

Run CMD as Administrator
pip3 install django

Answer (score 0):

If you had this error occur on windows after installing `django` using pip that has the message along the following lines:

> could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 2] The system
> cannot find the file specified: 'c:\python39\Scripts\sqlformat.exe'
> -> 'c:\python39\Scripts\sqlformat.exe.deleteme'

Which in turn causes the same problem as the question stated. A working solution is to clean installing `django` which you can do by using `pip uninstall django`, and then reinstalling it by running the install command like this: `pip install --user django`.

If no other warnings or errors occur, then it should be fixed. In case a warning sating that the `django-admin.exe` file is located at some location that needs to be added to the path variable, you can copy that path and add it to the path variable under your environment variable settings.

Quick fix guide:

1. Uninstall django: `pip uninstall django`.
2. Reinstall django: `pip install --user django`.
3. If a warning occurs containing a path continue to step 4 otherwise it should be fixed, and you may skip to the bottom.
4. Copy the path that should be added to the PATH environment variable.(the one specified in the warning)
5. Click on the start menu button.
6. Search for `Control Panel` and click on it.
7. Change the `View by:` option to `Large icons`.
8. Click on the `System` item.
9. Click on the `Advance system settings` button.
10. The `System Properties` window will open, proceed to click on the `Environment Variables...` button at the bottom right.
11. A new window will open displaying your Environment Variables, on the first gird select the row with the name of `PATH` or `Path` or `path` under the `Variable` column.
12. Then click the `Edit` button just below the grid.
13. A new window will open, proceed to click on the `New` button and paste the path you copied earlier.
14. After pasting press the `Enter` key and proceed to click on the `OK` button.
15. Once the window closes and you're back in the `Environment Variables` window proceed to do steps 11 to 14 again only with the grid at the bottom(inside the System Variables group).
16. Once all these steps were followed you may click on the `OK` button in the `Environment Variables` window and close out of all the other windows that are still open after you followed these steps.
17. Close your `CMD` window and open a new one (this allows it to recognize the changes you made to your environment variables).

After following these steps, you should be able to continue with what you were doing without having any other difficulties further regarding `Django`

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't getting the django-admin to run even after an hour of configuring PATH etc. That was all completely useless.

What actually WORKED was running the windows terminal (cmd) as admin and then doing "pip install django". Be sure to first uninstall it though using "pip uninstall django", so that you get a clean installation.

Now django-admin runs perfect on cmd with or without admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

Try Creating a python virtual environment in the given folder using

```
python -m venv venv
```

then activate the virtual environment using

```
venv\Scripts\activate
```

now use the pip command to install django

```
pip install django
```

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem. Open Terminal. Even if you have Django already installed in your project follow the below steps:

Type - `python -m django --version`

If it displays a version number start from Step 1 if not start from Step 2.

1. `pip uninstall Django`
   (A confirmation should pop-up requesting you to type Y/N. Go with Y)
2. `pip install Django`
   (Django should be installed without any issues)
3. `python -m django --version`
   (It should display the version number)
4. `djangoadmin`
   (This should display the list of available commands)

If step 4 works for you go ahead and enter `django-admin startproject <your project name>`. Please replace  with your project name.