# Add "django-admin.py" path to command line on Windows 7

Tags: python, django, windows, windows-7, cmd

I've been trying to add the `django-admin.py` path to command line on Windows 7.

I have tried to do it this way:

```
C:\>set django-admin.py = C:\Python27\Scripts\django-admin.py
```

But `cmd` told me that:

```
'django-admin.py' is not recognized as an internal or external command.
```

So how can I add `django-admin.py` path to command line on Windows 7?

I need it because later I'm doing this:

```
  C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\mysite>django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try following command.

```
set path=%path%;c:\python27\scripts
```

`PATH` is set only for the cmd.exe in which you run the above command.

**UPDATE**

To permanently set PATH:

1. Right click **My computer** in the desktop.
2. Click **Advanced System Settings** on the left.
3. Click **Environmental Variable**.
4. Add or Update `PATH` variable:

   - If it does not exist, create one, and set value as `C:\python27\scripts`
   - If it exist, append `;C:\Python27\scripts` to existing value.
5. Restart cmd.exe. (PATH will not change for already launched cmd.exe)

Comment: @MichaelVayvala, I added another way. Check it out.