# Add “python2” path to command line on Windows 7

Tags: python, windows, windows-7, path, cmd

I've been trying to add the `python2` path to command line on Windows 7.

I have tried to do it this way:

```
C:\>set python2 = C:\Python27\python.exe
```

But `cmd` told me that:

```
'python2' is not recognized as an internal or external command.
```

So how can I add `python2` path to command line on Windows 7?

Thanks.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This answer copied from [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17836439/2225682), and customized to this question.

Try following command.

```
set path=%path%;c:\python27
```

`PATH` is set only for the cmd.exe in which you run the above command.

To permanently set PATH:

1. Right click **My computer** in the desktop.
2. Click **Advanced System Settings** on the left.
3. Click **Environmental Variable**.
4. Add or Update `PATH` variable:

   - If it does not exist, create one, and set value as `C:\python27`
   - If it exist, append `;C:\Python27` to existing value.
5. Restart cmd.exe. (PATH will not change for already launched cmd.exe)

**UPDATE**

If you want to use **python2**, copy the executable.

```
CD C:\python27    
COPY python.exe python2.exe
```

Comment: @downvoter, How can I improve the answer? Please let me know what's wrong with the answer. I want to listen.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but it appears that the question is asking how to make the `python2` command appear in the `PATH`, but your answer shows how to get `python` into the `PATH` instead. I'm guessing the user has a script that is trying to specifically invoke Python2 in a mixed Python2/Python3 environment.

Comment: simply copying the executable solved the problem

Comment: does this override the `python` for python3.* command?

Answer (score 18):

Had the same problem and fixed it...
I have `C:\Python27`, which i have added to my environment variables which gave me access to "python" though the CMD.. but for installing node-sass though npm, which was my problem, it continues to say that "python2" is not found. A friend the told me i could just rename name executable, which i didn't belive, but it worked :-)

The rename was from:
`C:\Python27\python.exe` > `C:\Python27\python2.exe`

It works for me, even though it find it weird just renaming a file.. but then, i am not hardcore in the windows CMD.

Comment: This feels like it absolutely should not be the correct answer. That said with my environment variables set correctly all that required was to change the name of the executable to python2.exe and it worked! Upvote to you! Cheers

Comment: I just make a 2nd copy of python.exe with name python2.exe and it works for me. Thanks for you solution. Upvoted to you.

Comment: 2/7/21 and node-sass is still using pyhton2 smdh

Comment: I second @BanketeshvarNarayan 's comment. Seems like pip2 looks for the location of python.exe file.. so having two copies of the exe (python.exe and python2.exe) seems to work fine.

Comment: @Schalton I'm hitting the same problem and can't believe that it's still an issue. All because there's a `print` command using python 2's syntax... If I didn't just waste enough time to get behind on this project trying to figure out the solution, I'd make a pull request myself...

Comment: Splendid.  Simple, obvious (when you realise it) and brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it can be switched or not while keeping both python2 and python3.
But while working with python2 you can remove the "python3 path" from the PATH.
Cause By default in windows python3 is selected if both are installed. 
So you can try this to use python2. then when necessary again add the "python3 path " to the PATH

Answer (score 0):

although I add Python to path variable, it appeared further, I tried with Thor A. Pedersen's answer it worked, I found another way without rename `python.exe` to `python2.exe`, just update your node config as bellow. It worked for me.

`npm config set python python2.7`
or
`npm config set python python`