# 'python2' is not recognized as an internal or external command. Windows 10

Tags: python, python-2.7

How do I add `python2` to `PATH`? `python` works fine, however I am invoking a `make` file that points to many files with calls to `python2`.

```
C:\Users\andcy\$DETECTRON>python2
'python2' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Unfortunately, my search for related points brought me answers that did not apply. For example, the following SO post only shows how to add `python` to the path, not `python2`.

[Add “python2” path to command line on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17900954/add-python2-path-to-command-line-on-windows-7)

Comment: Have you tried `python` or `py` as a command line argument?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your `make` endpoints insist on `python2`, just `DOSKEY` a `python2` alias before calling your `make`, e.g.:

```
DOSKEY python2=python $*
```

If you're looking for something more permanent just create a `python2.cmd` file in the same directory as your Python binary (i.e. `python.exe`) to execute it on your behalf:

```
@echo off
"%~dp0\python.exe" %*
```

Or, as a quick and dirty solution, if you don't care about the `python.exe` itself just rename it to `python2.exe`.

Comment: Creating `python2.cmd` works, however, I would not recommend renaming python.exe to python2.exe as this can cause errors when trying to access the standard python 2 installation path