# How to create project of python-django in atom

Tags: python, django

I cannot create a project in Atom for Django Python

> django-admin is not recognized.

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure [Django PyPI package](https://pypi.org/project/Django/) is installed in your active Python interpreter environment, or better, create a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/) beforehand so as to isolate your project's dependencies from the rest of the system.

Comment: I created a virtual env named as MyDjangoEnv. Then I installed django through conda. I made a project folder my_Django by mkdir and cd my_Django. I activated the environment. What did i miss? So when I call django-admin startproject first_project. It is saying not recognized

Comment: Check if `django-admin` is in the system `PATH`.

Comment: can you please tell me how to check system PATH?

Comment: [How to set the path and environment variables in Windows](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm).

Comment: Yes I checked. No django-admin is not in the path. What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

If you have created `virtualenv` then you need to start it using these
command `env_name\Scripts\activate` then in cmd you will see the
command line as `(env_name) Path\to\project\:` then after check that you have installed `django` and required python version in that!

In above screenshot you didn't activated the `virtualenv`

In addition to that for setting path without virtualenv you just need to use this

command for setting `django-admin` is 
`set path=%path%;c:\python-version-directory\scripts`

OR you can refer this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836416/add-django-admin-py-path-to-command-line-on-windows-7)