# how to set django path in environment variables?

Tags: django, python-3.x

Here is my django bin folder path,

C:\Users\ELINE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\django\bin

I added this path to both system variables and user variables path variable. Also I created a new variable called 'django' in user variables and added this path. But when I type django in cmd(user directory) I get the following output,

'django' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

My operating system is windows.

Comment: You didn't install Django in your Windows PC. Firstly you have to install django with pip.

Comment: I have installed django using pip install django from cmd.

Comment: check this answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836416/add-django-admin-py-path-to-command-line-on-windows-7