# Unable to create Django Project

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a project in Django using CLI command **django-admin startproject MySQLCRUD**. But I am getting an error ie: **'django-admin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,                                                    operable program or batch file**. I tried various solution but couldn't get the error resolved. I already have Python and Django installed in my machine.

**Attached are the screenshots**

[image: DJango Error]

[image: Python and Django already installed]

**any solution please ?**

Comment: You should add `C:\<Python Installation Directory>\scripts` to your `PATH`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836416/

Comment: how about trying `django-admin.py startproject`