# Python django-admin startproject mysite

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

First timer here with Django and I am running into some issues trying to start the site with the Windows command prompt `django-admin startproject mysite`

My pip install worked as I can import the module and check the Django version. I am also running Python version 3.6...

```
>>> import django 
>>> print(django.get_version()) 
2.0.4
```

I also created a directory on my windows machine so my windows command prompt looks like this:

`C:\Users\b\Documents\Python\Django>django-admin startproject mysite`

But I am getting an error `'django-admin' is not a recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.'`

Any tips to try??? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your django command utility is not registered in your systems path (the environment variable `PATH` in your windows system).

Have you looked into [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769430/command-django-admin-py-startproject-mysite-not-recognized?rq=1) ? There are some pointers to get your machine up and running.

Answer (score 1):

Add in the PATH for Django-admin

Open:
Control Panel -> System -> Advanced -> Environment Variables -> PATH.

[image]

Click new as shown above and then find in your Windows machine where the django-admin files live in the hidden directory for the Python SCRIPTS.

On my machine its here:
C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts

Enter in PATH and your directory as shown below, then viola it should work
[image]