# 'django-admin' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. Windows10

Tags: python, django

I tried starting my own project in Django but I keep getting "'django-admin' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

```
C:\>cd C:\Users\Gamer Grill\Desktop

C:\Users\Gamer Grill\Desktop>mkdir django-practise

C:\Users\Gamer Grill\Desktop>cd django-practise

C:\Users\Gamer Grill\Desktop\django-practise>mkdir my_first_project

C:\Users\Gamer Grill\Desktop\django-practise>django-admin startproject first_project
'django-admin' is not recognized
```

Comment: Read [this documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-and-manage-py). You have to add `django-admin.exe` to your system PATH for it to be found in your shell.

Comment: @MihaiChelaru i got it! thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [command "django-admin.py startproject mysite" not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769430/command-django-admin-py-startproject-mysite-not-recognized)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest thing you can do is uninstall Python and when you install it again make sure the "add Python to Path" option is selected before you click install. After that go ahead and do your thing.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the way to do it is to

If you have installed django before with `pip install django`, you might have this problem.

So, to the cmd (command prompt) page and cd into your folder.
Next, you should make sure a virtual environment is activated but make sure not to run the command in the venv (virtual enviroment) as it will create your project in the venv.

Start by typing this command: `py -m pip install Django` for windows and `python -m pip install Django` for MacOS and Unix.

Try running the command with django-admin and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the Start menu and search for "Environment Variables."
2. Click on "Edit the system environment variables."
3. Click on the "Environment Variables" button.
4. Under "System Variables," scroll down to the "Path" variable and click "Edit."
5. Click "New" and enter the path to the Django executable files, which is typically "C:\PythonXX\Scripts" (where "XX" is the version number of Python you are using).

(in my PC the path is "C:\Python311\Scripts")

6. Click "OK" to close all windows.

After adding the path to the system's PATH environment variable, open a new command prompt and try running 'django-admin' again

Answer (score 0):

In my cases, the problem is that I rename the parent folder/directory of my virtual environment after I already did `virtualenv myenv`

I have to remove/delete the folder of my virtual environment `myenv` and recreate it again

```
virtualenv myenv
```

Again do activate the virtual env (by `cd` to virtual env
C:\path_to_parent_folder\myenv\Scripts\ folder and activate) and run

```
django-admin startproject mysite
```

The django project should be created successfully.

Answer (score -1):

It happens when you have installed python and `django-admin` in two different C: drive root folders.

Solution: copy `django-admin` file to `C://programfiles/pythonxxx/scripts` folder
[image: Python and django installation error link]

Comment: That link doesn't point to anywhere.

Answer (score -2):

At the time of writing, Python 3.7 is the latest version. Open the command prompt and check that the Python version matches the version:

```
...\> py --version
```

Now you can verify your Django installation by executing in the command prompt:

```
...\> django-admin --version
```

If you still have problems executing the above command, please install Django by executing in the command prompt:

```
...\> py -m pip install Django
```

After the installation has completed, you can verify your Django installation.

Regards.

Answer (score -4):

download the python from Microsoft store and not from the web and check the path of django-admin file . It might be coming with a warning on cmd prompt and that might be the issue.

Comment: FYI, Microsoft Store python is not recommended by python community, because MS Store apps have weird execution permissions which later show up as weird errors when trying to install libs or access files