# django-admin.py startproject can't create project on Windows.

Tags: django

I am on Windows server, and when I type "django-admin.py startproject", I'm getting the following message. Looks like I'm not using the command properly, but it is correct. My Django version is Django 1.10, and Pythhon 2.7.

```
c:\test>django-admin.py startproject mysite
Usage: django-admin.py subcommand [options] [args]

Options:
  -v VERBOSITY, --verbosity=VERBOSITY
                        Verbosity level; 0=minimal output, 1=normal output,
                        2=verbose output, 3=very verbose output
  --settings=SETTINGS   The Python path to a settings module, e.g.
                        "myproject.settings.main". If this isn't provided, the
                        DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable will be
                        used.
  --pythonpath=PYTHONPATH
                        A directory to add to the Python path, e.g.
                        "/home/djangoprojects/myproject".
  --traceback           Raise on exception
  --version             show program's version number and exit
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit

Type 'django-admin.py help <subcommand>' for help on a specific subcommand.

Available subcommands:

[django]
    check
    cleanup
    compilemessages
    createcachetable
    dbshell
    diffsettings
    dumpdata
    flush
    inspectdb
    loaddata
    makemessages
    runfcgi
    runserver
    shell
    sql
    sqlall
    sqlclear
    sqlcustom
    sqldropindexes
    sqlflush
    sqlindexes
    sqlinitialdata
    sqlsequencereset
    startapp
    startproject
    syncdb
    test
    testserver
    validate
```

Comment: Are you using virtual environment or have Django installed globally?

Answer (score 3):

Simply try this :

```
 django-admin startproject projectname
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
python djangoadmin.py startproject mysite
```

or check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3237555/1161025).